# Jquery click event fails for button with multiple classes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a form with button as follows. Here click event is not triggered.

```
<form role="form" method="POST" id="exportform" action="{{ route('export_pdf') }}">
  <input type="checkbox"  name="dataoption[]" id="filled-in-box5" value="1"  />
  <input type="checkbox"  name="dataoption[]" id="filled-in-box7" value="2"/>
  <button type="button" class="btn-floating pdf-btn page"><i class="material-icons">picture_as_pdf</i></button>
</form>


<script type="text/javascript">

   $(document).on('click',"[type='button'][class='page']",function(){
      // do action 
  });
</script>
```

But when I change the code as

```
 $(document).on('click',".page",function(){
      // do action 
  });
```

or as

```
<button type="button" class="page"><i class="material-icons">picture_as_pdf</i></button>

$(document).on('click',"class['page']",function(){
          // do action 
      });
```

it works. But I need to check both type and class to fire action. Why is this not possible when multiple classes exist? How can I make it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what you need to type to make it trigger the class and the type

```
$(document).on('click',".page[type=button]",function(){
      // do action 
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

please try this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $(".page[type='button']").click(function(){
     alert('clicked');
   })
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case it's easier to use the action listener like this:

```
$('.page').on('click',function(){
     // do action 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
 $(document).on('click',".page[type='button']",function(){
     alert("working..");
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form role="form" method="POST" id="exportform" action="{{ route('export_pdf') }}">
  <input type="checkbox"  name="dataoption[]" id="filled-in-box5" value="1"  />
  <input type="checkbox"  name="dataoption[]" id="filled-in-box7" value="2"/>
  <button type="button" class="btn-floating pdf-btn page"><i class="material-icons">picture_as_pdf</i></button>
</form>
```